# Error running JMeter remotely in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I would like to use one EC2 instance as a controller for 1 or more remote server instances in Amazon. I can start and run the test (on the remote side it runs) but the controller never exits. It fails with:

> 2015/02/12 17:34:25 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Engine is busy - please try later
>           at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.rconfigure(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:151)

If I run the test w/o the -R  it works fine.

The same test setup works in SoftLayer so I think it is a firewall issue but I think I have put all the ports into my security group.

Comment: By default the jmeter server will open a connection to the client (master) on a random port. Easiest is to put them on the same network, or read up on the documentation: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html 
I don't know whether this is the cause of your problem or not I'm, but it could very well be that the server cannot connect to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter use Java RMI for distributed tests. This protocol is sensible for using different networks or firewalls.

For EC2 I suggest to use:

1. [Amazon VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) for creating own virtual network for Jmeter instances.
2. Use ssh tunnels between Jmeter machines - this type of conenction is usually more stable and better "debuggable" then RMI